# Word for "work completed on behalf of"

Tags: single-word-requests

I hope you can help. I am updating my CV/résumé and I am using one word for each section. I must admit I am stumped in one area.

I need a single word to convey the following description:

"Work completed on behalf of"

This is where I have carried out work (graphic design and web development) for other companies while working for my main company (e.g external rather than internal work).

Comment: [Freelancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freelancer) is a relevant term, but the freelancer is usually self-employed. Since you do work in a primary organization, while working for other companies on the side, not sure if _freelancing_ would fit perfectly in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single word that can make up a section heading, then **Clients** or perhaps even better *External clients* is probably a good fit. "Client" is a reasonably well-understood term to mean "someone who is the final receiver of the product created", but unlike [Lascivious Grace](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/79984/lascivious-grace)'s suggestion of *freelancing* need not imply any particular form of employment.

---

**However,** I'm wondering if it might not perhaps be even better to put this into your regular employment history section, rather than as a section of its own? In which case, you could write something like (note that this uses the same word, just not as a section heading):

> 2009 -- 2013, Acme Designs, Corp., graphics designer and web developer, with **clients** including Coyote Hospital, Inc. (2010 -- 2013); Funny Movies, Corp. (2009); and Acme Explosives, LLC. (2009 -- 2011)

You could then break that up (bullet point list, newlines, ...) however you feel fits your resume's style best.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try *secondment*:

> the process or state of being seconded, the temporary transfer of a
>   person from their normal duty to another assignment

source: Wiktionary

Comment: A word that nobody will understand is helpful to whom, exactly?

Comment: @Robusto managers, sales people and politicians.